# Commerce: Show quantity discounts

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, promotions

### starting point

I have the following offer with quantity discounts for a series of my products:

- Buy 1 item and get $5 off per item
- Buy 2 items and get $10 off per item
- Buy 3 items and get $15 off per item

I set these **discount rules** in my control panel under "commerce" > "promotions".

---

### product template

Now in my product template, I would like to be able to output (for each quantity level):

1. the normal (non-discounted) price
2. the discounted price
3. savings in terms of $
4. savings in terms of %

---

### example

For example it would then say on the product page (output):

> "If you buy 2 items, you only pay $[*discount price for 2 items*]
>   instead of $[*normal price*] per item. So your total today is only
>   $[*2 x discount price for 2 items*] insted of $[*2 x normal price*].
>   You therefore save $[(2 x normal price)-(2 x discount price for 2
>   items)]. That's a discount of […]%."

The same goes for the discount offer of ordering 1 item or 3 items.

---

**How can I accomplish this with all the discounts and math operations involved?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

The [documentation](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/discounts) seems to be missing, but looking at `/craft/plugins/commerce/models/Commerce_DiscountModel.php` you can find the properties `purchaseQty` and `perItemDiscount` that you need for the calculations.

```
{% for prod in product.variants %}
   {% for discount in craft.commerce.discounts %}
      {% set totalPrice = (discount.purchaseQty * prod.price) %}
      {% set totalDiscountPrice = (discount.purchaseQty * (prod.price + discount.perItemDiscount)) %}
      {% set totalDiscount = (totalPrice-totalDiscountPrice) %}
      {% set totalDiscountPercent = (totalDiscount/totalPrice)*100 %}

      <p>If you buy {{ discount.purchaseQty }} items, you only pay {{ totalDiscountPrice|currency(cart.currency) }} instead of {{ prod.price|currency(cart.currency) }} per item. So your total today is only {{ totalDiscountPrice|currency(cart.currency) }} insted of {{ totalPrice|currency(cart.currency) }}. You therefore save {{ totalDiscount|currency(cart.currency) }}. That's a discount of {{ totalDiscountPercent|round }}%.</p>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will show all of the discounts for all of the products. You will need to modify it slightly if you have specified the discount for a specific product. You also need to check if the discount is enabled or not using `discount.enabled`

Comment: Hi Alex, it works great! I have added this: `{% set discountPricePerItem = (prod.price + discount.perItemDiscount) %}` to be able to display the "per item"-price on each discount level. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have specific discount rules for each product separately. How can I modify this code so it would show ONLY the product specific discounts and NOT all the discounts?

Comment: Also, `{% if discount.enabled == true %}` doesn't work. Do I need to write this differently?

Comment: Can you please open it as a new question so that I can give you a proper answer rather than just in a comment?

Comment: I used this to filter product specific discounts: `{% if product.id in discount.productIds or product.typeId in discount.productTypeIds %}` – and it works